# How do I use format with variables?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

Currently, I’m trying to make the words in my string align, so I tried using formatting:

```
a = “Hi”
b = “He”
“{0} {1: (5 - len(a))}”.format(a,b)
```

I wanted to create a string that has a consistant starting point for the second word, so that it’s exactly 5 away from the start of the line (5 - len(a) spaces from the end of the first word)like:

```
I    H
III  L
IIIIIH
```

I’m guessing it’s reading this as a string instead of a value (5-len(a)), so how would I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is usually more beneficial if the title/question reflects the *real* ask or goal, which is probably more like “How to specify fixed-width output with format?”. If the ask is about a specific implementation, make sure such is also clear.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for

```
"{:<10}{}".format(a, b)
```

This is documented here https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html

For variable padding (thanks @Tomerikoo):

```
x = 10 
"{:<{size}}{}".format(a, b, size=x)
```

Comment: If I don’t know the maximum length of the first word, is it possible to use a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `repr(x).rjust(width)` to make strings out of your variables, and print those right justified (or `ljust()` or `center()`).